# (Python 3) Trouble with output

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am trying to create a number grade to letter grade converter that takes user input, then spits out the letter grade equivalent. My problem is, whenever I input a number it spits out just the letter grade and then below that it spits out 'Your letter grade is None!'

My goal is to make it to where it spits out 'Your letter grade is (letter_grade)!"

Code is below:

```
grade = int(input("Please enter what you made on the test here:"))

def grade_converter(grade):
    if grade >= 94 and grade <= 100:
        return "A"
    elif grade >= 90 and grade < 94:
        return "A-"
    elif grade >=87 and grade < 90:
        return "B+"
    elif grade >= 84 and grade < 87:
        return "B"
    elif grade >= 80 and grade < 84:
        return "B-"
    elif grade >= 77 and grade < 80:
        return "C+"
    elif grade >= 74 and grade < 77:
        return "C"
    elif grade >= 70 and grade < 74:
        return "C-"
    elif grade >= 67 and grade < 70:
        return "D+"
    elif grade >= 64 and grade < 67:
        return "D"
    elif grade >= 61 and grade < 64:
        return "D-"
    else:
        return "F"

letter_grade = print(grade_converter(grade))

print("Your letter grade is " + str(letter_grade) + "!")
```

Comment: note that `94 <= grade <= 100` works and is often easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to change is the following line

```
letter_grade = print(grade_converter(grade))
```

to

```
letter_grade = grade_converter(grade)
```

**Why?**
because print does not return anything.

**Running till user closes the program**
modify everything to the following except the function

```
while(True):
    grade = int(input("Please enter what you made on the test here:"))
    letter_grade = grade_converter(grade)
    print("Your letter grade is " + str(letter_grade) + "!")
```

Comment: One more thing: I want this to loop over and over until the user closes the program. I wrapped the whole function (besides the 'def' line of code) in 'while True'. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I could come with **2 solutions** for your Code. Change your code to this,

```
    letter_grade = grade_converter(grade)
```

One thing I would like to mention is that you are actually returning values as strings therefore you don't need to **type cast** it again to **str** in your **last** **print** **statement**.

So Instead of this,

```
    letter_grade = grade_converter(grade)

    print("Your letter grade is " + str(letter_grade) + "!")
```

Just replace it with this,

```
    print("Your letter grade is " + grade_converter(grade) + "!")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    grade = int(input("Please enter what you made on the test here:"))
    if grade != -1:
        def grade_converter(grade):
            if grade >= 94 and grade <= 100:
                return "A"
            elif grade >= 90 and grade < 94:
                return "A-"
            elif grade >=87 and grade < 90:
                return "B+"
            elif grade >= 84 and grade < 87:
                return "B"
            elif grade >= 80 and grade < 84:
                return "B-"
            elif grade >= 77 and grade < 80:
                return "C+"
            elif grade >= 74 and grade < 77:
                return "C"
            elif grade >= 70 and grade < 74:
                return "C-"
            elif grade >= 67 and grade < 70:
                return "D+"
            elif grade >= 64 and grade < 67:
                return "D"
            elif grade >= 61 and grade < 64:
                return "D-"
            else:
                return "F"

        letter_grade = grade_converter(grade)

        print("Your letter grade is " + str(letter_grade) + "!")
    else:
        break
```

If grade != -1 When the user does not input "-1" the program will continue.

Every-time it goes through the loop, it would print a new statement, which is why the print statement is inside of the "if" statement.

else: if the user inputs "-1" the program will stop using "break" syntax.